# How are you doing CI with Unity and Git with 3rd party assets?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, continuous-integration

My goal is to be able to build Unity projects with 3rd party assets using GitHub Actions and GameCI. I am able to build and deploy Unity projects on Git, but I have the following problem.
I don't want to check in 3rd party assets, but I do want to build on Git.

Many of the licenses are not open source, and checking them into a repository seems problematic even when the repo is private.
Is there a way to download assets from a command line using a Unity license during the build process? Or is there a better way to manage Unity 3rd party assets in Git with CI?

Comment: I'd claim this is a general problem/grey zone. The CI is supposed to take away heavy CPU time from your local device.. I would claim that having bought a license for a 3th party software it is totally fine to build with it also via CI (in doubt ask the makers of that 3th party library) .. usually you should have a license per seat e.g. but a CI I personally wouldn't see as an additional seat

Comment: CI is more than taking away heavy CPU time. You do CI so you can avoid the "it builds on my machine" problem, runs tests after code is checked in to verify the build still works, can create multiple artifacts for different platforms, etc. CI is a must, but it seems to break down in Unity once you start adding 3rd party code.

I don't think the licenses are the issue. Its that they shouldn't be checked in (waste of Git space, and makes the repo forever private), and they should be downloaded as part of the build process.

Comment: in that case nothing hinders you from doing the same process of downloading and integrating them into your project as you do locally ... you just need to know where they have to be unpacked e.g. or you can run scripts in Unity via console as well ... https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EditorCommandLineArguments.html .. and implemented according method into your project